# Is there a limit to how many Approval processes there can be in a single workflow?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am creating a SharePoint 2010 Workflow that depending on certain conditions will execute a certain Approval Process. I have recently hit a 6th approval process, since then I am unable to publish my WF.

If I remove one of them, I can successfully publish. Is there a limit to how many Approval processes there can be in a single workflow?

Comment: Me sucede los mismo por favor alguien sabe algo al respecto?

Comment: Can you please check total number of workflow variables?

Comment: @SamirKhimani, thatnks for your response. I am no longer in the position for this question. Thanks again!